# Accessing protected members from subclasses: gcc vs msvc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, visual-c++

In visual C++, I can do things like this:

```
template <class T>
class A{
protected:
    T i;
};

template <class T>
class B : public A<T>{
    T geti() {return i;}
};
```

If I try to compile this in g++, I get an error.  I have to do this:

```
template <class T>
class B : public A<T>{
    T geti() {return A<T>::i;}
};
```

Am I not supposed to do the former in standard C++?  Or is something misconfigured with gcc that's giving me errors?

Comment: Which version(s) of gcc?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405/template-problem-with-gcc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This used to be allowed, but changed in [gcc 3.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html#cplusplus).

In a template definition, unqualified names will no longer find members of a dependent base (as specified by [temp.dep]/3 in the C++ standard). For example,

```
    template <typename T> struct B {
      int m;
      int n;
      int f ();
      int g ();
    };
    int n;
    int g ();
    template <typename T> struct C : B<T> {
      void h ()
      {
        m = 0; // error
        f ();  // error
        n = 0; // ::n is modified
        g ();  // ::g is called
      }
    };
```

You must make the names dependent, e.g. by prefixing them with this->. Here is the corrected definition of C::h,

```
    template <typename T> void C<T>::h ()
    {
      this->m = 0;
      this->f ();
      this->n = 0
      this->g ();
    }
```

Comment: Heh... you must have posted at the same time I did.  It's strange that msvc accepts that even though it's invalid (and was causing weird runtime errors).

Comment: Ya, I seen your post right after I found the release notes.  I think probably old versions of both gcc and vc++ supported the wrong way.  But gcc chose to make it right and vc++ chose to keep backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this one out:

- [C++ Super FAQ: "Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a nested type it inherits from its template-base-class?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types)
- [C++ Super FAQ: "Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members)

Apparently, the first example ISN'T valid C++ and it's bad that msvc takes this.  There are solutions posted on the C++ faq lite.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about [two-phase name lookup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/TwoPhaseLookup.aspx)