# C++ "was not declared in this scope" when overriding a pure virtual method in a derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, scope, overriding

here is what I need to do :

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                              

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public :
    virtual void fa() = 0;
};

template <typename type>
class B : public A
{
    protected :
    int v_b;
};

template <typename type>
class C : public B<type>
{
    public :
    void fa()
    {
        // whatever action that try to access v_b
        cout << "v_b = " << v_b << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<int> toto;
    toto.fa();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is g++ output :

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void C<type>::fa()’:
test.cpp:25:29: error: ‘v_b’ was not declared in this scope
```

In my understanding, v_b is a protected member of B and is therefore accessible in C. A and B are both abstract classes, and I need to override the f_a() method of A in class C in order to instanciate it. Since the compiler is telling me this

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void C<type>::fa()’:
```

and **NOT**

```
‘void A::fa()’:
```

i don't get why the v_b variable is not present in the scope. Is this a problem in the way I use templates?

Can anyone help me out on that one ?

thx

**edit :**

I tryed to use this->v_b or B<type>::v_b as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281072/accessing-public-members-of-base-class-fails) and it **worked fine** ! thx for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing public members of base class fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281072/accessing-public-members-of-base-class-fails)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624564/access-protected-member-of-a-class-in-a-derived-class

Comment: `this->v_b` will fix the code. The links from @CharlesBailey explain why.

Comment: Are you using an older version of g++? http://ideone.com/fBXNK

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

(sry if you answered before I suppressed the part where it didn't work with the "second technique", it was another unrelated mistake)

thx for the links

Comment: My example shows it working with `this->`

Comment: @bames53 you're right it was just me being doing it wrong !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression:

```
    cout << "v_b = " << v_b << endl;
```

`v_b` is a non-dependent expression (i.e. it does not *look* like it depends on the template arguments. For a non-dependent expression the first phase lookup must resolve the symbol, and it will do so by looking only in non-dependent contexts. This does not include a templated base (as it does depend on the type argument). The simple fix is to qualify the call with `this`:

```
    cout << "v_b = " << this->v_b << endl;
```

Now it is a *dependent* expression (`this` which clearly depends on the instantiating type), and lookup is delayed to the second phase where the type is substituted and the bases can be checked.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, even faster than my edit ! I tried to look in that direction but I still have issues that I don't understand. Would you please have a look at what happened ? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: no you're right ! when trying to test different solutions, as desperate as it may look, I left a
"template <typename type>
class C : public B<typename type>
{" when i made my edit ! Thx for pointing this out ! I can sleep now ;)