# protected member is not accessible by base class as expected

Tags: c++

My derived class merge_sort from dynamic_array does not have access to protected member T* array.  Their are error everywhere it is used saying such.

I'm not sure why...except maybe the public designator for merge_sort should be something else?

```
#include "c_include.cpp"
using namespace std;
template <class T> class dynamic_array
  {
  protected:
    T* array;
  public:
    int size;
    void rorder();
    void order();
    void randorder();
    void print_operator(ostream&)const;
    dynamic_array(int sizein)
      {
      size=sizein;
      array=new T[size]();
      }
  };
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::print_operator(ostream &os=cout)const
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) os << array[i] << endl;
  }
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::randorder()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int *ap;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap){*ap=rand();} 
  }
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::order()
  {
  int *ap,i=0;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap)                                             
    { 
    *ap=i;
    ++i;        
    } 
  }
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::rorder()
  {
  int *ap,i=size;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap)                                             
    { 
    *ap=i;
    --i;        
    } 
  }
template<class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, dynamic_array<T> const& data) 
  { 
  data.print_operator(stream);
  return stream; 
  }   
/*
Merge Sort
*/
template <class T> class merge_sort : public dynamic_array <T>
  {
  private:
    const static int size;
    int scratch[];
    void flip_if_unordered(int &x, int &y)
      {
      if(array[x]>array[y])
        {
        int tmp=array[x];
        array[x]=array[y];
        array[y]=tmp;
        }
      }
    void merge_algo(int &left, int &right_begin, int &right)
      {
      int iter,iter_left=left,iter_right=right_begin;  
      for(iter=left;iter<=right;++iter)
        {
        if( (iter_right>right) || ((iter_left < right_begin) && (array[iter_left]<=array[iter_right])))
          {
          scratch[iter]=array[iter_left];
          ++iter_left;
          }
        else
          {
          scratch[iter]=array[iter_right];
          ++iter_right;
          }
        }
      for(iter=left;iter<=right;++iter){array[iter]=scratch[iter];}
      }
    void merge_recurse(int left,int right)
      {
      int left_end=(left+((right-left)/2)); 
      int right_begin=left_end+1;  
      if(((left+1)==right)){flip_if_unordered(left,right);return;}
      else if ((left==right)){return;}
      else
        { 
        merge_recurse(left,left_end);               
        merge_recurse(right_begin,right);  
        merge_algo(left,right_begin,right);
        }   
      }
  public:
    merge_sort()
      {
      scratch = new T[size]();
      if(scratch != NULL)
        {
        merge_recurse(0, size);
        }
      }
  };

/*Quick Sort

    void quick_sort()
      {
      quick_recurse(0,size);
      }

    void quick_recurse(int left, int right) 
      {  
      int l = left, r = right, tmp;
      int pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
      while (l <= r)
        {
        while (array[l] < pivot)l++;
        while (array[r] > pivot)r--;
        if (l <= r) 
          {
          tmp = array[l];
          array[l] = array[r];
          array[r] = tmp;
          l++;
          r--;
          }
        }
      if (left < r)quick_recurse(left, r);
      if (l < right)quick_recurse(l, right);
      }  
*/
```

Comment: What's the error message and where you will get it?

Comment: error array was not declared in this scope

Comment: It would be much more useful if you posted a minimal testcase, since I am sure the issue you vaguely talk about (why not tell at least a problematic line, and why the commented out code?) can be reproduced in a couple of lines. Also not many people will be able to parse "Their are error everywhere it is used saying such?"

Comment: This question is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624564/access-protected-member-of-a-class-in-a-derived-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base class depends on a template argument, so its type is a dependent type. The compiler won't know which specialization of the base class you use until is instantiated, so you have to help the compiler know that such identifier is a base's member. Either like this:

```
dynamic_array<T>::array
```

or

```
this->array
```

or

```
using dynamic_array<T>::array;
```

Comment: Thanks...that one template I started with for my dynamic_array is all over the place now as far as syntax goes...thank you

Comment: Can I use a typedef for dynamic_array<T>::array to make it more concise?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: `dynamic_array<T>::array` is not a type, so you can't use a `typedef`. Place `using dynamic_array<T>::array;` in your class and it will make the base member visible using just `array`.

Comment: place it where ? in my class ? under the the public section?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: If you place it under the `public` section you have just changed its visibility to `public`. Place it under a `protected` section instead.