# Why can't I access protected member in static polymorphic derived class?

Tags: c++

This works fine:

```
    class A{
    protected:
    int i;
    };

    class B:public A{
    public:
    void f(){
        i=5; //fine
      }
    };
```

However if I try to do the same with static polymorphism, it fails:

```
template <class Derived, typename T, int N>
class Vector{

protected:

std::vector<T> v;
```

Then:

```
  template <typename T, int N>
  class Vector234:public Vector<Vector234<T, N>,T,N>{

    void test(){
        T t=v[0]; // v is undeclared identifier
    }
```

Why is this?

Comment: This is addressed in questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624564/access-protected-member-of-a-class-in-a-derived-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405/gcc-problem-using-a-member-of-a-base-class-that-depends-on-a-template-argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a dependent name, that is, it depends on the template parameter `T`. You need to explicitly specify either `this->v[0]` or `Vector<Vector234<T, N>,T,N>::v[0]`.