# Inherited template classes

Tags: class, templates, inheritance

First - I'm know this is really noob question - but hey - we all start with being noobs, aren't we?...
So, to the Q:
I'm want to use inherited template classes, and I've having hard time dealing with this stuff. This is the code, written in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
protected:
    int f(){return 0};
};

template <class T>
class B : public A<T>
{
protected:
    int f2()
    {
        return this->;
    }
};
```

Thing is, in the auto-complete option, I used to see all B 'variables', which are actual B variables **along A variables**. But when I use template - I can see only class B variables, when writing down "this->".
(Needless to say - when I delete the template declarations - it worked out just fine, and "this->" will give me both f() **and** f2() options)
Is there's anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a duplicate of this one:

[templates: parent class member variables not visible in inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592512/templates-parent-class-member-variables-not-visible-in-inherited-class?rq=1)

the first answer of UncleBens sums it up very well.

> [...]the template parent of a template class is not instantiated during the 
>   compilation pass that first examines the template.[...]

He also gives further information and a good link for further reading.