# Inheritance and template in C++: Why doesn't the following piece of code compile?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, g++

I have a simple c++ program , which I am not able to compile , although i tried to search in google and try to read about template , inheritance and vector , but i didn't got any clue that what mistake I am doing, Can anyone please help me!!
following is the code:

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
  public:
  int entries;
};
template <class T>
class Derive : public Base<T *>
{
  public:
  int j;
  void pankaj(){j = entries;}
  void clear();

};
template <class T> void Derive<T>::clear()
{
  int i;
  int j=entries;
};
int main()
{
  Derive b1;
}
```

And I am getting following error:
pankajkk> g++ sample.cpp

```
sample.cpp: In member function 'void Derive<T>::pankaj()':
sample.cpp:14: error: 'entries' was not declared in this scope
sample.cpp: In member function 'void Derive<T>::clear()':
sample.cpp:22: error: 'entries' was not declared in this scope
sample.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sample.cpp:26: error: missing template arguments before 'b1'
sample.cpp:26: error: expected `;' before 'b1'
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What's up with all that whitespace?

Comment: removed extra whitespace.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That does work, but why doesn't it work without `this->`? FWIW `Base<T*>::entries` works as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772960/c-template-inheritance-scheme

Comment: @KarolyHorvath  it worked after changing entries to this->entries. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

You must use `this->foo` to access member variable `foo` in template base classes. [You may ask why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

Also, as *Old Fox* explains, you must specify the type `T` when you declare your variable `b1`.

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
  public:
  int entries;
};

template <class T>
class Derive : public Base<T *>
{
  public:
  int j;
  void pankaj(){j = this->entries;}
  void clear();
};

template <class T> void Derive<T>::clear()
{
  int i;
  int j=this->entries;
};

int main()
{
  Derive<int> b1;
}
```

[live demo here](http://ideone.com/HGjJ0K)

Answer (score 1):

your main method has syntax error, change to:

```
int main()
{
    Derive<int> b1;
}
```

you can put other type rather than integer...

in c++ templates are [compile time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29)

Comment: @cmbasnett , I took his code into visual studio, after my change it was compiled without any error

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't mean the code is correct... blame VS.

Comment: @Old Fox - Fair enough, I use VS too, but it looks like VS doesn't conform to the C++ standard, as per the link in the comments in the OP.

Comment: @OldFox It fixed compiler error at line no. 26 , But I am still getting other error.

Comment: @OldFox I am compiling using g++ 4.9.

Comment: @pankajkushwaha ,Karoly Horvath was right, the right syntax is this->entries

Comment: @OldFox yup , it compiled after changing entries to this->entries. Thanks karoly , thanks OldFox