# Member from base class template not found

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

I have a class hierarchy like the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
protected:
    T t;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {
public:
    T get() { return t; }
};

int main() {
    Derived<int> d;
    d.get();
}
```

The problem is that the protected [member variable t is not found in the Base class](http://ideone.com/GraWLC). Compiler output:

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'T Derived<T>::get()':
prog.cpp:10:22: error: 't' was not declared in this scope
```

Is that correct compiler behavior or just a compiler bug? If it is correct, why is it so? What is the best workaround?

Using fully qualified name works, but it seems to be unnecessarily verbose:

```
T get() { return Base<T>::t; }
```

Comment: You have to use `this->`. This is a duplicate I believe.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I need to use `this->`, so I was not able to find the very good explanation in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use members from template base classes, you have to prefix with `this->`.

```
template<typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {
public:
    T get() { return this->t; }
};
```