# Why does the compiler require a this-> prefix in certain situations when mixing templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, this

Consider this code:

```
  template <typename T>
  struct X{
     struct Y{
          unsigned i;
     };

    template<typename E>
    struct Z : public Y {

       unsigned foo(){
          return i;
       }
    };


  };
```

we have a class template `X` with nested classes `Y` and `Z`. `Z` is again a template and inherits from `Y`. Thus, it also inherits the field `i`. However, this code does not compile. The compiles says, that it cannot resolve `i` in the `foo()` method of `Z`. Prefixing `i` explicitly with `this->` solves the problem.

If I remove the outer type `X`, then the prefix is no longer required and the code compiles fine as it is.

Why is this explicit `this->` prefix required here?

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/4643074/1741542.