# Why the derived class cannot access protected base class members?

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

I have a base class (VectorRaw) and a derived class (Vector).

I use operator new in the constructor of the base class to create a memory buffer and then placement new in the constructor of the derived class to place elements therein.

The base class has its virtual destructor which cleans up if something in the constructor of the derived class goes wrong.

When I try to compile it, there is an error: all of the base class' members (`begin, end, end_of_reserved`) are out of scope in all derived classes' functions.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
template <typename T>
class VectorRaw {
protected:
    T * begin;
    T * end;
    T * end_of_reserved;

    VectorRaw(const size_t size) {
        begin = (T*) operator new (2 * size * sizeof(T));
        end = begin;
        end_of_reserved = begin + 2 * size;
    }
    virtual ~VectorRaw<T> () throw() {
        for (T * iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
            iter->~T();
        }
        operator delete (begin);
        end_of_reserved = end = begin;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Vector : public VectorRaw<T> {
public: 
    Vector(const size_t size, const T& value) : VectorRaw<T>(size) {
        for (end = begin; end != begin + size; ++end)
            {   
            new (end) T (value);
        }
    }
    bool Empty() const throw() {
        return (begin == end);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your base class is a template class, you need to access the members through the `this` pointer:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector : public VectorRaw<T> {
public: 
    Vector(const size_t size, const T& value) : VectorRaw<T>(size) {
        for (this->end = begin; this->end != this->begin + size; ++this->end)
            {   
            new (this->end) T (value);
        }
    }
    bool Empty() const {
        return (this->begin == this->end);
    }

};
```

This is necessary to defer the lookup of these names until the template parameter is known. It makes them *dependent names*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643295/150634) for more details.

Comment: interesting! I actually tried this, but then my compiler complains about operator new(size_t) and proposes to use operator new(size_t, void*) which doesn't allocate any storage

Comment: You are using the non-placement operators wrong. Change `begin = (T*) operator new (2 * size * sizeof(T));` to `begin = new T[2 * size];` and `operator delete (begin);` to `delete[] begin;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, could you please explain the difference? In documentation I see for operator new[]:"The default definition allocates memory by calling operator new: ::operator new (size)"