# C++: Why Protected Constructor Cannot be Accessed in the Derived Class?

Tags: c++, protected

Protected member is supposed to be accessible from derived class.
Then, why I got the compiling error in the code below?

```
class A {
protected:
    A() {};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void g() { 
        A a; // <--- compiling error: "Protected function A::A() is not accessible ...". Why?
    }
};


int main() {
    B b;
    b.g();
}
```

I noticed there is a related post, but the class there is a template class. Mine is just a "regular" class.

[Why the derived class cannot access protected base class members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452948/why-the-derived-class-cannot-access-protected-base-class-members)

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff, yes. fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`protected` members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access) could be accessed from derived class, but only when through the derived class.

> A `protected` member of a class is only accessible
>
> 1. ...
> 2. to the members `and friends (until C++17)` of any derived class of that class, but only when the class of the object through which the protected member is accessed is that derived class or a derived class of that derived class:

So you can't create an indpendent object of base class even in member functions of derived class.

Put it in another way, the `protected` members of the current instance of derived class could be accessed, but `protected` members of independent base class can't. E.g.

```
class A {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    A() : x(0) {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void g() {
        this->x = 42; // fine. access protected member through derived class
        A a;
        a.x = 42;     // error. access protected member through base class
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to initialize `A a;` from `B` if the constructor remains `protected` though (as in the original example)?

Comment: @glinka No, you just can't create a separate base class object.

Answer (score 0):

> Protected member is supposed to be accessible from derived class.

Yes, but only when accessed via the `this` pointer. Not when accessed on a complety separate object. Which you are trying to do, when `B::g()` tries to construct a new `A` object.