# Accessing inherited objects from class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, g++

I've been learning C++ templating and I've run across some weird behavior. Consider this class structure (stripped down from my original code):

```
class A {
public:
    std::vector <int> vec;
};

template <typename T> class B : public A {  };

template <typename T> class C : public B<T> {
public:
    using A::vec;
    int test() {
        return vec[1];      // OK
    }

    int test2() {
        return vec.size();  // error: 'class A' has no member named 'size'
    }
};
```

When compiling, I get an error in `test2`, saying that `class A` has no member `size`. But `vec` should be a `vector` object, not an instance of `A`. Indeed, if I derive `C` directly from `A` instead of `B<T>`, or remove the template from `C`, it compiles fine.

Furthermore, if I add the following method to `C`:

```
int test3() {
    void ***v = vec;        // error: cannot convert from
                            // 'std::vector<int,...>'  to 'void***' 
}
```

the compiler says it can't convert from a `vector<int>` to `void***`, so it seems to know the correct type for `vec`. Am I making a mistake here, or is this possibly a bug in my compiler? I'm using an Apple version of g++ 4.2.1. Edit: also seems to occur in later versions of g++.

Thanks for your help!

**Second edit**: my compiler is happy if I use `this->vec.size()` in `test2` instead of relying on the `using A::vec` declaration.

Comment: [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4643074/341970)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code compiles with clang (see it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fec20f05917ad8db)), and doesn't compile with [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f22340c6b0133ffe). I also got it to compile with VS2013.

---

Your original issue is related to how the compiler lookup names in templates.

The Standard § 14.6.2 :

> Non-dependent names used in a template definition are found using the
>   usual name lookup and bound at the point they are used.

Also the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html) has a good entry about it :

> The compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like B) when
>   looking up nondependent names (like vec).

---

**Solution** :

**1.** Use `this->vec` (this is always **implicitly dependent** in a template)

```
int test2() {
    return this->vec.size();  
}
```

**2.** Use `using B<T>::vec`

**3.** Use `B<T>` directly :

```
int test2() {
    return B<T>::vec.size();  
}
```

---

**Notes:**

- I'm not sure why gcc refuses `using A::vec;`, looks like a compiler bug to me (and note that `using B<T>::A::vec;` works).
- Standard reference for template names lookup : § 14.6.3 and § 14.6.4

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I read quickly about the issue with nondependent names and dependent base classes (and that's where I learned the 'using A::vec' syntax). But, I didn't know you could stack scope resolution operators like B<T>::A::vec -- that's good to know.