# Is there a way to get around having to prefix template base class members with `this`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

When inheriting from a template class, I need to prefix all base class members I access in the derived class with `this`:

```
template<typename T>
struct X{
   int foo;
   void bar();
};

template<typename T>
struct Y : public X<T> {

   void blub(){
       foo++; // Does not work
       this->foo++; // Fine
       bar(); // Does not work
       this->bar(); // Fine
   }
}
```

As I was hinted, the reason why you must prefix the members with `this` has already been answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer). So my remaining question is: Is there a way to avoid all the `this`es? For example, I have a method in the derived class that uses a lot of base class members. The code looks totally cluttered with all the `this->` in it. Is there a way to omit these?

Comment: It's explained in a million places on Stack Overflow, just search around for five (more) minutes.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I tried to search for my question first. I could not find it. In addition, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Good search keyword: "dependent names"

Comment: @Angew: Didn't know about these keywords. However, I tried searching for "C++ dependent names" and "template this dependent names" and got no matching results.

Comment: @gexicide You can get around it with a `using` declaration. See the canonical ["Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords? "](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1782465).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

Comment: @Angew: How can it be avoided with `using`? That would be interesting, but I cannot find it in the question you linked.

Comment: @Constructor: Interesting, yes, that question explains it. But it does not give a hint whether and how it can be avoided.

Comment: @gexicide Write `using X<T>::foo;` in your `Y` class template.

Comment: I have rephrased the question so it only asks how it can be circumvented, not why it is the case. I have added a link to the question that explains why. @Constructor: Interesting, I will try that. You can also phrase it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make this work, you need to turn the non-dependent names `foo` and `bar` into dependent names.  There are three ways to do this:

- Qualify them with `this`, as you have done.  This has the downside that you need to do it everywhere you use the names.  `this` is implicitly a dependent name.
- Qualify them with the base class name, as `X<T>::foo` and `X<T>::bar`.  This also needs to be done everywhere you use them, and additionally breaks the virtual dispatch mechanism if they turn out to be virtual methods.
- Bring the dependent names into the non-dependent namespace by `using X<T>::foo;` and `using X<T>::bar;`.

Or, you can compile with VC++ which couldn't care less about the distinction between dependent and non-dependent names.

Comment: @Drax My life is currently hell because of this.  I'm porting a large code base from VC++ to GCC.  The rest of the team is still developing in VC++.  It doesn't matter how often you explain the dependent/non-dependent distinction to them, they keep on breaking it and can't see what's wrong.  "But it compiles fine for me..."

Comment: Is the thing about VC++ still true today? Because it doesn't seem to work. Maybe there's some option for it?

Comment: @SWdV - very late comment, but I believe the VC++ compiler manages to get this right these days.  Back when this was written, it was dire; not only did it not care about this distinction, it also didn't bother parsing template bodies until they were used, meaning you put put very nearly anything in the body of a template, so long as it was not used; the bug wouldn't become apparent until someone else used it and suddenly years-old template code won't compile.