# C++ operator overloading or redefine?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload + for Point+Point and Point+vector

```
class Vector
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

class  PointBase
{
public:

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

        PointBase operator+(const Vector &vec) const
        {
            PointBase b;
            b.x=vec.x+this->x;
            b.y=vec.y+this->y;
            b.z=vec.z+this->z;
            return b;

        }
};

class  Point:public PointBase
{
public:
    PointBase operator+(const Point &point) const
    {
        PointBase b;
        b.x=point.x+this->x;
        b.y=point.y+this->y;
        b.z=point.z+this->z;
        return b;
    }
    Point(PointBase& base)
    {
    }
    Point()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Point  p;
    Vector v;
    p=p+v;
    return 0;
}
```

`PointBase operator+(const Point &point) const` hides   `PointBase operator+(const Vector &vec) const`, why? I expect that 2 overloads work correctly: `point+vector` and `point +point`.

Comment: What's the point of the `PointBase` class? A class like `Point` does not sound like it should derive from anything.

Comment: Consider putting the operator into the surrounding namespace instead of making it a member function. This is also the only way to implement operators where the left operand is a builtin type, like e.g. `operator*` for `float` and `Vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator+` in `Point` hides the one inherited from `PointBase`. To make it available, use

```
class  Point:public PointBase
{
public:
  using PointBase::operator+;  // <-- here

  PointBase operator+(const Point &point) const

  // rest as before
```

Note, however, that the next problem you'll run into is that

```
p=p+v
```

attempts to use an `operator=` that takes a `Point` on the left and a `PointBase` on the right and that does not exist.

The reason that the `operator+` in the derived class hides the one in the base class is the way name lookup works in C++: The compiler goes outward in layers (concrete class -> base class -> base base class -> ..., and for non-member functions called from a member function continues through the surrounding namespaces<sup>1</sup>) until it finds a matching name, tries to apply it, and fails if that doesn't work. You can see the same mechanism at work in this non-compiling piece of code:

```
void foo(char const *) { }

namespace bar {
  void foo(int) { }

  void baz() {
    // does not compile: bar::foo hides ::foo
    foo("hello");
  }
}
```

In the case of your classes, the compiler looks in `Point`, finds a matching name, tries to apply it, and complains when it fails. It does not continue to look in the surrounding scope (`PointBase`), but it would continue to look if it had not found the `operator+` in `Point`.

<sup>1</sup> There's an asterisk for class templates that inherit other class templates here, where different mechanisms come into play. See [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer) for details, although none of that comes into play in your case.