# Specify the templated base class as the source of derived class variable

Tags: c++

I am currently porting some code from Visual studio to mingw and their are instances in the code when variables in the base class are being used inside the methods in a derived class. For instance

```
template<typename t>
struct base_foo 
{
  int foo;
};

template<typename t>
struct derived_foo : public base_foo<t> 
{
  void some_method();
};

template<typename t>
void derived_foo<t>::some_method()
{
  foo = 12 ; //Error variable not declared in this scope
  base_foo<t>::foo = 12 ; //OK
}
```

Now there are many instances like this in my code and wanted to know if there was a way for me to state that if there is a variable that isnt found locally look in the base class. In short
if the following gives an error

```
   foo = 12 ;
```

then try

```
base_foo<t>::foo = 12;
```

Comment: Instead of `base_foo<t>::`, you could use `this->` as well.

Comment: The better option is to fix all your broken code. Note you can also say `this->foo`.

Comment: Actually, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer) might be the better dupe.