# Using variables from parent class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, dependent-name

I've been trying to use template to implement stack. And my question is how do I use the variables from the parent class in this situation?

In this case my compile error is: 'top, a, size' was not declared in this scope.

```
    template<class T>
        class buffer
        {
  public:
            T *a;
            int top,i,size;
        };

    template<class T>
        class Queue: public buffer<T>
        {
    public:
            Queue(int siz)
            {
                a=new T[siz];
                size=siz;
                top=-1;
            }
            void push(T ele)
            {
                if(top!=size-1){a[++top]=ele;} 
            }

            T pop()
            {
                  return(a[top--]);
            }

            void print()
            {
                for(i=0;i<top;i++)
                    cout<<" "<<a[i];

                cout<<endl;
            }
        };
```

Comment: It compiles for me, what other code are you using here?

Comment: `i` should be local variable and not member.

Comment: BTW, your inheritance is strange... You don't respect rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: [Explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

Comment: @meneldal I think the real qusetion is *which MSVC version are you using* ;)

Comment: @M.M I forgot how MSVC messed up that one. I didn't see anything that shouldn't not compile in that code. It seems that it's been fixed for a while now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make them dependent name, you have to use `this->` or `buffer<T>::` before.

so

```
this->a = new T[siz];
this->size = siz;
this->top = -1;
```