# Visibility problems when using CRTP

Tags: c++11, crtp

Here's a minimal example I could come up with:

```
template <typename T>
struct Util
{
    using Type = int;
};

struct A
{
    struct B : public Util<B> {
        void fun(Type) {}
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct C
{
    struct D : public Util<D> {
        void fun(Type) {}
    };
};

int main()
{
    A::B{}.fun(0);
    C<int>::D{}.fun(0);
}
```

The only difference between `A::B` and `C::D` is that `C` is a template.

Struct `C::D` fails to compile with the following error:

```
test_cpp.cpp:18:18: error: ‘Type’ has not been declared
         void fun(Type) {}
                  ^~~~
```

Why does this fails to compile? How do I make this compile?

Assume that Util is from external library and I cannot change it (it's `boost::iterator_facade` if you're courious).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point:

```
template <typename T>
struct C
{
    struct D : public Util<D> {
        void fun(Type) {} // <-- here
    };
};
```

The compiler *has no way of knowing* * that `Type` needs to come from `Util<D>`'s scope. It's the same issue with calling base class member functions, which need to be qualified explicitly with `this->` or they won't be found.

You should be able to fix this by explicitly qualifying the type:

```
void fun(typename Util<D>::Type) {}
```

See [complete snippet on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bac1162e304507f0).

The reason behind the difference is, as @etam1024 correctly points out in a comment, that in `A::B`, `Type` is a non-dependent name, and in `C::D` it is a dependent name. See for an explanation of a similar situation regarding member function qualification of base class member functions [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer/4643295#4643295).

* In my opinion, the compiler *can* know where to look for `Type`, but the language rules say it doesn't look that far. Note I might be overlooking special cases where it is impossible for the compiler to deduce this, hence leading to the general case requiring full koalafication.

Comment: Thanks! I'd add that in `A::B` the `Type` is a "nondependent name" and in `C::D` it is a "dependent name" (it depends on template argument). https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types