# Moving a member function from base class to derived class breaks the program for no obvious reason

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, namespaces

> This (made-up) question was initially formulated as a puzzle, concealing 
>   some of the details that might help seeing the problem faster. Scroll down
>   for the simpler [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version.

---

## Original (a-la puzzle) version

I have this piece of code that outputs `0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

regex sig_regex("[0-9]+");
bool oldmode = false;

template<class T>
struct B
{
    T bitset;

    explicit B(T flags) : bitset(flags) {}

    bool foo(T n, string s)
    {
        return bitset < 32                   // The mouth is not full of teeth
               && 63 > (~n & 255) == oldmode // Fooness holds
               && regex_match(s, sig_regex); // Signature matches
    }
};

template<class T>
struct D : B<T>
{
    D(T flags) : B<T>(flags) {}

};

int main()
{
    D<uint64_t> d(128 | 16 | 1);
    cout << d.foo(7, "123") << endl;
}
```

However, when I move the function `foo()` from `B` to `D` it starts outputting `1` ([proof is on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b2464c54204660d)).

Why does this happen?

---

## MCVE version

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8844fa1b85e1785)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct B
{
    T bitset{0};

    bool foo(int x)
    {
        return bitset < 32 && 63 > (x + 1) == x % 2;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct D : B<T>
{
    bool bar(int x) // This is identical to B<T>::foo()
    {
        return bitset < 32 && 63 > (x + 1) == x % 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D<uint64_t> d;
    cout << d.foo(1) << endl; // outputs 1
    cout << d.bar(1) << endl; // outputs 0; So how is bar() different from foo()?
}
```

Comment: Which bit of the `return` expression in `foo` changes?

Comment: This is a valid on-topic question; the vote-to-close is incorrect.

Comment: Is the code sample supposed to be unnecessarily non-minimal and confusing? If not, I'd suggest just including `<bitset>` and getting rid of the whole `regex` red herring.

Comment: You should have tried making this code simpler before posting.

Comment: "[...] is this meant as a test [...]" --> "No[...]" --> "[...] question was initially formulated as a puzzle[...]". I don't know whether stackoverflow is the place to ask questions you already know the answer to without answering it while making it extra difficult to spot the problem.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is why you should never `using namespace std;`

```
bool foo(T n, string s)
{
    return bitset < 32                  
           && 63 > (~n & 255) == oldmode 
           && regex_match(s, sig_regex);
}
```

That `bitset` isn't what you think it is. Because `B<T>` is a dependent base class, members are hidden from unqualified lookup. So to access `bitset`, you need to access it through `this`<sup>1</sup>, or explicitly qualify it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer) for more details):

```
(this->bitset)
B<T>::bitset
```

Because `bitset` doesn't name `B<T>::bitset` in the derived case, what could it mean? Well, because you wrote `using namespace std;`, it's actually `std::bitset`, and the rest of your expression just so happens to be valid. Here's what happens:

```
bool foo(T n, string s)
{
    return std::bitset<32 && 63>(~n & 255) == oldmode 
           && regex_match(s, sig_regex);
}
```

The `32 && 63` evaluates to `true`, which is promoted to `1u` for the `std::bitset` template argument. This `std::bitset` is initialized with `~n & 255`, and is checked for equality with `oldmode`. This last step is valid because `std::bitset` has a non-explicit constructor which allows a temporary `std::bitset<1>` to be constructed from `oldmode`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that we need to parenthesise `this->bitset` in this case due to some pretty subtle parsing disambiguity rules. See [Template dependent base member is not resolved properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470650/template-dependent-base-member-is-not-resolved-properly) for details.

Comment: *"... and the rest of your expression just so happens to be valid"* Do you really believe that this is indeed by coincidence? (:

Comment: @Leon Why, is this meant as a test rather than an actual question?

Comment: No, it was meant as a demonstration of how context dependent C++ is. Your explanation of the "problem" is a great one.

Comment: @TartanLlama `this->bitset` doesn't compile either, it look like explicit name qual. `B<T>::bitset` is the only way to go. At least gcc6.2 still believes `this->bitset` refers to `std::bitset'.

Comment: @vsoftco: That's rather surprising behavior :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed, I have absolutely no clue why it happens. Just realized that clang also chokes on it.

Comment: @vsoftco Even if you drop the `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @TartanLlama Will you please update your answer taking account of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470650/template-dependent-base-member-is-not-resolved-properly ?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, because `bitset` will be interpreted as non-dependent name, and there is a template named `std::bitset<T>`, hence, it will be parsed as:

```
template<class T>
struct D : B<T>
{
    D(T flags) : B<T>(flags) {}
    bool foo(T n, string s)
    {
        return ((std::bitset < 32  && 63 > (~n & 255)) == oldmode)
               && regex_match(s, sig_regex);
    }
};
```

You need to make it like this:

```
template<class T>
struct D : B<T>
{
    D(T flags) : B<T>(flags) {}

    bool foo(T n, string s)
    {
        // or return B<T>::bitset
        return (this->B<T>::bitset < 32)                   // The mouth is not full of teeth
               && 63 > (~n & 255) == oldmode // Fooness holds
               && regex_match(s, sig_regex); // Signature matches
    }
};
```

or better, don't use `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 9):

> 1. Why does this happen?

For the derived class, `B<T>` is not a nondependent base class, it can't be determined without knowing the template argument. And `bitset` is a nondependent name, which won't be looked up in dependent base class. Instead, `std::bitset` is used here (because of `using namespace std;`). So you'll get:

```
return std::bitset<32 && 63>(~n & 255) == oldmode
       && regex_match(s, sig_regex);
```

You could make the name `bitset` dependent; because dependent names can be looked up only at the time of instantiation, and at that time the exact base specialization that must be explored will be known. For example:

```
return this->bitset < 32                   // The mouth is not full of teeth
//     ~~~~~~
       && 63 > (~n & 255) == oldmode       // Fooness holds
       && regex_match(s, sig_regex);       // Signature matches
```

or

```
return B<T>::bitset < 32                   // The mouth is not full of teeth
//     ~~~~~~
       && 63 > (~n & 255) == oldmode       // Fooness holds
       && regex_match(s, sig_regex);       // Signature matches
```

or

```
using B<T>::bitset;
return bitset < 32                   // The mouth is not full of teeth
       && 63 > (~n & 255) == oldmode // Fooness holds
       && regex_match(s, sig_regex); // Signature matches
```

> 2. What should the title of this question be, after it is answered?

"How to access the nondependent names in template base class?"

Answer (score 3):

This is a really cool example!!! :)

I think - what is happening is this:

```
bitset < 32 && 63 >(~n & 255)
```

Is parses as construct me a `bitset`