# Inherited member function seems undeclared, what is going on?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I would like to compile a C++ software which gives me a couple of compilation
errors. This error is about a member function that cannot be resolved.

This question should contain everything needed to answer it. However, if that
really was the case, I should have found the answer by now. So please feel free
to browse the [source
code](https://github.com/martin-ueding/bfm/tree/fee0a02554073434f3f8a54304580e47ee834e61/bfm).
All code in this question is not mine but licensed under the GPLv2.

The system I compile on is an IBM PowerPC 740 running Red Hat Enterprise Server
6.8. Using modules, I have enabled Clang 3.7. Everything gets cross-compiled
for IBM PowerPC A2 chips, it is an IBM BlueGene/Q supercomputer. Those things
should be taken care by my [compilation
script](https://github.com/martin-ueding/chroma-auxiliary-scripts/blob/014c9e823a96d492b325a2aaf743038413dc1152/compilation/bootstrap-chroma-juqueen.sh#L243)
that sets the many `configure` and `CXXFLAGS` needed.

The compilation error that I currently get with the my current state (commit
`fee0a02`) is this one:

```
bfmcommqmp.C:183:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gather'
    gather(result_cb, psi, dag);
    ^
```

The offending line is in this method definition in `bfmcommqmp.C`:

```
168 template <class Float>                                                          
169 void bfmcommQMP<Float>::comm_start(int result_cb, Fermion_t psi, int dag) {     
170     // gather the faces. Routines here are threaded.                            
171     // All threads cooperate in gathering.                                      
172                                                                                 
173     //  if ( this->isBoss() && (me == 0)) {                                     
174     //    this->Error("comm_start checking heap\n"); fflush(stdout);            
175     //    mcheck_check_all();                                                   
176     //    this->Error("comm_start mcheck_all");fflush(stdout);                  
177     //  }                                                                       
178                                                                                 
179     int me = this->thread_barrier();                                            
180                                                                                 
181     this->thread_barrier();                                                     
182                                                                                 
183     gather(result_cb, psi, dag);                                                
184                                                                                 
185     this->thread_barrier();                                                     
186     if (me == 0) {                                                              
187         comm_qmp_start(psi);                                                    
188     }                                                                           
189     this->thread_barrier();                                                     
190                                                                                 
191     return;                                                                     
192 }
```

This is of course part of the `bfmcommQMP` class. Looking at the associated
header file, `bfmcommqmp.h`, one finds this class declaration:

```
  8 template <class Float>                                                          
  9 class bfmcommQMP : public bfmbase<Float> {                                      
 10   public:                                                                       
 11     // QMP thingy-me-bob's                                                      
 12     QMP_msghandle_t multi_handle[2];                                            
 13                                                                                 
 14     QMP_msgmem_t send_ops_msgmem_t[8];                                          
 15     QMP_msgmem_t recv_ops_msgmem_t[8];                                          
 16                                                                                 
 17     QMP_msghandle_t send_multi_handle;                                          
 18     QMP_msghandle_t send_handles[8];                                            
 19                                                                                 
 20     QMP_msghandle_t recv_handles[8];                                            
 21     QMP_msghandle_t all_handles;                                                
 22                                                                                 
 23     Float *simd_rbuf[8];                                                        
 24     Float *receive_area;                                                        
 25                                                                                 
 26     int num_op;                                                                 
 27                                                                                 
 28     virtual bool isBoss();                                                      
 29                                                                                 
 30     virtual void recv_init(void);                                               
 31     virtual void recv_end(void);                                                
 32                                                                                 
 33     virtual void comm_init(void);                                               
 34     virtual void comm_end(void);                                                
 35     virtual void comm(int result_cb, Fermion_t psi, int dag);                   
 36     virtual void comm_start(int result_cb, Fermion_t psi, int dag);             
 37     virtual void comm_qmp_start(Fermion_t psi);                                 
 38     virtual void comm_qmp_complete(void);                                       
 39     virtual void comm_merge(void);                                              
 40     virtual void comm_complete(int result_cb, Fermion_t psi);                   
 41     virtual void comm_gsum(double &val);                                        
 42     virtual void comm_gsum(double *val, int N);                                 
 43 };
```

It inherits from `bfmbase`. Jumping to the file `bfm.h` which is included in
`bfmcommqmp.h`, we find the class definition, which contains two `gather`
methods:

```
 133 template <class Float>                                                          
 134 class bfmbase : public bfmarg, public ThreadModel {                             
 135   public:  

 282     void gather(int result_cb, Fermion_t psi, int dag);
 283     void gather(int mu, int result_cb, Fermion_t psi, int dag); 

1018 };
```

From my understanding, the class `bfmcommQMP` should have inherited the
non-virtual function `gather` from `bfmbase`. Apparently that is not the case,
otherwise Clang would not complain about that.

What am I missing here? Why is the function `gather` not available inside the
`bfmcommQMP::comm_start` member function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your derived class is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name). You need to qualify the call to `gather()` in the base class with `this->gather()` instead, otherwise the compiler does not resolve `gather()` from the base class. To simplify,

```
template<class T> struct Base
{
    void f();
};

template<class T> struct Derived: Base<T> // dependent name
{
    void foo()
    {
        this->f(); // won't compile without this->
    }
};
```

An alternative is to do

```
using Base::f;
```

in the derived `Derived::foo()` or qualify the call like

```
Base::f();
```

Related: [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643074/3093378)

Comment: This also explains why every other invocation in that method is prefixed with `this->`! Now I get some other compilation error, this one seems solved. Thank you very much, I was looking everywhere else and would not have ever thought that something like this might be the cause.

Comment: You're welcome. [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://www.amazon.com/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0201734842) is, imo, the best book on templates, tells you everything you ever wondered about templates. Old (2002) but still very relevant. The authors are working on an update to modern C++ (C++11 and later).