# C++ Name Resolution in Template Subclass-of-Subclass

Tags: c++, data-members

I am trying to access base-class data in my C++ code without using the "this" pointer.  My classes are templated, and `ClassA` is the base class for `ClassB`, which is the base class for `ClassC`.  All classes are publicly derived from their base classes. I found this discussion which gets me half-way to a solution, but doesn't resolve it completely:

[Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

That page suggests I should be able to fix my problem with the "using" statement.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename FP>
class ClassA
{
    protected:
    FP a ;
} ;

template <typename FP>
class ClassB : public ClassA <FP>
{
    using ClassA <FP> :: a ;
    public:
    void fooB ( void ) { std:: cout << a << std::endl ; }
} ;

template <typename FP>
class ClassC : public ClassB <FP>
{
    using ClassA <FP> :: a ;
    public:
    void fooC ( void ) { std:: cout << a << std::endl ; }
} ;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
    ClassB <double> tempB ;
    ClassC <double> tempC ;

    tempB.fooB ( ) ;
    tempC.fooC ( ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The code above fails to compile, giving the error below:

```
stepTWO.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class ClassC<double>’:
stepTWO.cpp:30:25:   required from here
stepTWO.cpp:8:12: error: ‘double ClassA<double>::a’ is protected
         FP a ;
            ^
 stepTWO.cpp:20:11: error: within this context
     class ClassC : public ClassB <FP>
```

What I've found is that "using" will make the variable accessible in *either* `ClassB` *or* `ClassC`, but not both.  If I put the using statement in both classes, I get the error shown above.  All inheritance is done through public derivation.

Does anyone know of a solution to make this work?  (Other than using "this" or fully-qualified scope names to access my data elements?)

Comment: Have you tried making the symbol `protected` in `ClassB`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Thanks! Until these suggestions, I didn't realize that sort of thing mattered in terms of "using".  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that in `ClassB` the `using ClassA <FP> :: a ;` is in the private section of the class.  That means a derived class will not be able to access it.  What you need to do is put it in a protected section like the variable is declared `ClassA`.  Doing that you get:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename FP>
class ClassA
{
    protected:
    FP a ;
} ;

template <typename FP>
class ClassB : public ClassA <FP>
{
    protected:
    using ClassA <FP> :: a ; // protected so it can be inherited
    public:
    void fooB ( void ) { std:: cout << a << std::endl ; }
} ;

template <typename FP>
class ClassC : public ClassB <FP>
{
    using ClassA <FP> :: a ;
    public:
    void fooC ( void ) { std:: cout << a << std::endl ; }
} ;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
    ClassB <double> tempB ;
    ClassC <double> tempC ;

    tempB.fooB ( ) ;
    tempC.fooC ( ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```