# Inhertiance with Templates - Variable does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have the following code example below, with two template classes, one base and one derived. I need to access a type in the base class from the derived class, but it says that it does not name a type. Why is this the case?

```
'Parameter' does not name a type
```

---

```
using namespace std;

template<typename PointT>
class BaseClass{
public:
    BaseClass(){}

    class Parameter{
        Parameter(){}
    };
};

template<typename PointT>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<PointT>{
public:
    DerivedClass(){}

    class ParameterExtended{
        Parameter x;
    };
};
```

Comment: typename BaseClass<PointT>::Parameter x;

Comment: where do i add this?

Comment: use it instead of `Parameter x;`

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
typename BaseClass<PointT>::Parameter x;
```

Comment: this seems to work. Also, i can't seem to access any variables from my base class either in the derived class. says its not declared in this scope

Comment: @Raaj Maybe [this is the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)?