# 'using Base<T>::func()' in derived class makes 'func' inaccessible outside of derived class

Tags: c++, templates

This is C++. I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    T t;
    void use() {cout << "base" << endl;};
};

template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {
using Base<T>::use;

public:
   T x;
   void print() { use(); };

};

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Derived<float> *s = new Derived<float>();

    s->Base<float>::use(); // this is okay
    s->use();  // compiler complaints that "void Base<T>::use() is inaccessible"

    s->print(); // this is okay

    return 0;
}
```

Base::use() does not use the template typename T. According to [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer), I used 'using Base::use' in Derived so I can refer to it as 'use' in Derived::print(). However, I cannot call use() via a pointer to Derived anymore. What would cause this?

Comment: You did the `using` in a private context within the class `Derived`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have the line

```
using Base<T>::use;
```

in the `public` section of `Derived`.

```
template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {

public:
   using Base<T>::use;
   T x;
   void print() { use(); };

};
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/I5rmEw).