# Accessing static data through inheritance of a template template parameter?

Tags: c++11, templates, inheritance, static, policy-based-design

```
template
<
    template <typename, typename>
        class storage_t,
    typename T,
    typename is_allocated
>
class Buffer : public storage_t<T, is_allocated> { ... };

template
<
    template <typename, typename>
        class storage_t,
    typename T = storage::UnknownType,
    typename is_allocated = std::false_type
>
class Example_Buffer
: public Buffer<storage_t, T, is_allocated> {
    constexpr Example_Buffer(
        typename storage_t<T, is_allocated>::iterator it) {}
};
```

`Example_Buffer<...>` inherits from `Buffer<...>`. `Buffer<storage_t, T, is_allocated>` inherits from `storage_t<T, is_allocated>`. `storage_t<...>` includes `typedefs` and static constexpr data. Is there a way to access these `typedefs` and `static constexpr data` in the constructor of `Example_Buffer` through inheritance? (through inheritance, that is, not using `storage_t<T, is_allocated>`? It feels slightly odd to use this syntax twice within the same class.

Feel free to ask if I need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members are inherited and accessible as long as they are public in storage_t. You can use the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) and/or the injected base class name to access these dependent members,

Here are a few options..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename A,typename B>
struct basic_storage
{
    using a_type = A;
    using b_type = B;
    static constexpr bool value = b_type::value;
};


template
<
    template <typename, typename>
        class storage_t,
    typename T,
    typename is_allocated
>
class Buffer : public storage_t<T, is_allocated> {

    public:
    using storage_type = storage_t<T, is_allocated>;
};

template
<
    template <typename, typename>
        class storage_t,
    typename T /*= storage::UnknownType*/,
    typename is_allocated = std::false_type
>
class Example_Buffer
: public Buffer<storage_t, T, is_allocated> {
    public:
    constexpr Example_Buffer(
        /*typename storage_t<T, is_allocated>::iterator it*/) {

            //using the members with the injected class name..
            using b_type = typename Example_Buffer::b_type;

            // or directly using injected class name..
            std::cout << typeid(typename Example_Buffer::a_type).name() << std::endl;
            std::cout << Example_Buffer::value << std::endl;

            // using storage_type defined in Buffer<...>
            using storage_type = typename Example_Buffer::storage_type;

            std::cout << typeid(typename storage_type::a_type).name() << std::endl;
            std::cout << storage_type::b_type::value << std::endl;
            std::cout << storage_type::value << std::endl;

        }
};


int main() {
    Example_Buffer<basic_storage,int,std::true_type>{};
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/PLzF5p)

If your wondering why you cant just access then in the derived class without prefixing them with `Example_Buffer::` base class name, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer) explains it is because they are dependent names.