# Member was not declared in base class template

Tags: c++, templates

The codes comprises 1 header file and 1 source file. I have cut the irrelevent codes and still maintain the compilation error.

Huffman.h

```
#ifndef HUFFMAN
#define HUFFMAN
template<int size>
class Huffman{
protected:
    int code_len[size];
    int code[size];
    void genCode(){
    }
};
template<int size>
class HuffmanEncode :public Huffman<size>{
public:
    void f(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            code_len[i] = 0;
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include"Huffman.h"
int main()
{
    HuffmanEncode<256> h;
}
```

The member variable `code_len` is defined in the base class. I don't know why it said `code_len` is undefined.

Comment: Try `this->code_len[i] = 0;` I am sure there is a duplicate for this.

Comment: I don't think this deserves so many downvotes. It's not at all obvious, and not that easy to find duplicates without already knowing the cause.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case for templates. The problem is that the nondependent name `code_len` won't be looked up in the scope of dependent base class `Huffman` (which depends on template parameter `size`).

You could make the name `code_len` dependent, then it will be looked up only at the time of instantiation; at that time the template argument has been known and the base class has been instantiated, then the name `code_len` could be found at the scope of base class (like non-template base class). e.g.

```
this->code_len[i] = 0;
```

or

```
Huffman<size>::code_len[i] = 0;
```

Comment: I think you should make it clearer in the answer that the reason specifically is because the base class is a template where the template parameter depends on the derived class's template parameter.