# Template method accesses forward declared class fails to compile only without this pointer

Tags: c++, templates, this, language-lawyer, forward-declaration

When I compile the following code with the latest Visual Studio, it success to compile.

```
class C;

class T
{
public:
    template<typename A>
    void f();

private:
    C* c;
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.f<int>();
}

template<typename A>
void T::f()
{
    this->c->g();
}

class C
{
public:
    void g() {}
};
```

But when I remove `this->` from `this->c->g()`, compilation fails with `C2027: use of undefined type 'C'`.

When I make the method `f` non-template, it fails to compile no matter `this->` presents or not, so I think it's related to template compiling/instantiating, but I can't really figure out. I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643295/5986794), but isn't `c` and `g` unambiguous in `T::f()`?

So, the question is: **What's the role of `this->` here?**

---

Compiler Differences:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------+
|                       | Template, w/ this-> | Template, w/o this-> | Non-Template |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| Visual Studio 16.3.10 | Success             | Fail                 | Fail         |
| x64 msvc v19.24       | Success             | Success              | Fail         |
| x86-64 gcc 9.2        | Success w/ warning  | Success w/ warning   | Fail         |
| x86-64 clang 9.0.0    | Fail                | Fail                 | Fail         |
+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

`x64 msvc v19.24`, `x86-64 gcc 9.2` and `x86-64 clang 9.0.0` are tested with Compiler Explorer.

Comment: I think this _should_ fail to compile, so really only clang is correct. When `T.f<int>()` is first instantiated, it doesn't yet have the definition of `C`, and therefore should fail.

Comment: @ChrisMM Well, it should fail at the template definition, not just at instantiation. GCC's also "right" in that it knows it should be failing.

Comment: @HTNW, why would the template definition not be okay? If the definition `C` is moved before the definition of `template<typename A> void T::f()`, then it would be correct. Or, is this what you mean?

Comment: @ChrisMM `T` is not dependent on `A`, therefore `this` is not dependent on `A`, therefore the access to `c` is not dependent on `A`, therefore the access of `g` in `C` is not dependent on `A`, therefore it should be checked at the definition of the template and not at its instantiations, therefore the template itself is ill-formed. It would be well-formed if the definition of `C` is visible at the template definition.

Comment: @HTNW, _Non-dependent names used in a template definition are found using the usual name lookup and **bound at the point they are used.**_ In OP's example, `this->c->g()` isn't used in the template definition, only in the `T::f()` definition. It is still ill-formed as is, since `c` (with or without `this`) does not have a full definition of `C` yet. So yes, not the instantiation of `T.f<int>()` like I said in my first comment, that was incorrect of me. It is when `T::f()` is beging defined.

Comment: @ChrisMM there is some distinctions in compilers about how template compilation is processed. In MSVC only a few checks are performed at template definitions, most only performed at template instantiations. Some other compilers test too much unnecessarily on template definitions. It is a mess overall. This shouldn't compile at the template instantiation. Hell, the definition shouldn't be visible at all at the call. So it probably compiles at all due to some bug.

Comment: @ALX23z, MS actually says on their website they improperly parse templates like this, and that they violate the clause I quoted above. (`[temp.nondep]`)

Comment: @ALX23z msvc claim to have fixed all that stuff, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is ill-formed NDR due to C++17 [temp.res]/8.3:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - [...]
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter,

The hypothetical instantiation is ill-formed because `c->g` is used when `c` has pointer to incomplete type, and that is not affected by the template parameter `A`.

So it is a quality of implementation issue whether an error is raised.