# C++: IntelliSense fails for templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, struct, visual-studio-2019

```cpp
template <class T, class U> struct Additional {
    T t;
    U u;
};
template <class T, class U> struct Base {
    void test1() {
        additional-> // members are shown here
    }
    Additional<T, U>* additional;
};
template <class T, class U> struct Derived : Base<T, U> {
    void test2() {
        additional-> // IntelliSense: 'No members available'
    }
};
```

I marked with comments the points of interest. The goal is to access suggested members inside `test2()`. At the first time I tried to declare a template `struct` inside another template `struct` (`Additional` in `Base`), but the notation became complex so I switched to keep `Additional` outside. I'm making dynamic containers for kernel driver usage. VS2019, Win 10, latest updates for both. Some suggested variants that did not work:

```cpp
template <class T, class U> struct Derived : Base<T, U> {
    void test2() {
        this->additional-> // This one passed the compile
    }
};
template <class T, class U> struct Derived : Base<T, U> {
    void test2() {
        Base<T, U>::
    }
};
template <class T, class U> struct Derived : Base<T, U> {
    using Base<T, U>::additional;
    void test2() {
        additional->
    }
};
```

Comment: Fairly certain this is the same underlying issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer

Comment: `using Base<T,U>::additional`, `Base<T,U>::` or `this->` doesn't work. All does not show the members of `additional`, or doesn't show the `additional` at all (2nd case)

Comment: I made some edits containing suggestions