# Visual Studio Intellisense not working when inheriting from template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Here is a testing snippet involving inheriting from template classes:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct A {
    T x;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : public A<T> {
    B(T x, T y) : A<T>{ x }, y{ y } { }
    T y;
};

template <typename T>
struct C : public B<T> {
    C(T x, T y, T z) : B<T>{ x, y }, z{ z } { }
    T z;

    // when I typed `this->`, Intellisense didn't give me the option `x`,
    // which is iherited from `A<T>` and should appear in the autocomplete pop-up.
    // In contrast, `this->` did give the option `y`.
    void test() { cout << this->x << ", " << this->y << ", " << z << endl; }
};

int main() {
    C<int> c{ 1, 2, 3 };
    c.test();  // prints out `1, 2, 3` as expected
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs. But in `void C<T>::test()`, when I tried to access the member `x` defined in the indirect base class `A<T>` using `this` pointer, `x` didn't show up in the Intellisense autocomplete pop-up. On the other hand, the directly inherited member `y` did show-up.

I tested with VS2019 and VSCode+gcc, both of which gave similar results.

But I know that Intellisense is a very powerful engine, so I wonder if I'm doing inheritance from template classes correctly or not? If I'm wrong, what is the proper way?

Comment: Intellisense is not as accurate as the compiler proper.  It can (and does) make mistakes.

Comment: why use `this->` to get to `x`

Comment: @rioV8 x is not a dependent name in the context of a class template, see [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

Comment: @LeonCruz You can still learn a new C++ thing every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get the same situation in my side. And I think it is a real issue of **C++ Intellisense** rather than **C++ syntax standard**.

**In fact**, the project builds and runs well and can print the value of `x` without any errors, which proves that the issue is not related to **C++ syntax standard**.

**And it is just a pure C++ IntelliSense problem. And Intellisense cannot get the member from the second-level struct.**

I have [reported the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1249256/why-intellisense-cannot-get-the-member-from-the-se.html). And you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

**Suggestion**

**Since** the process might take a long time, as a suggestion, so far, you could also let struct `C` inherit `A`. And **Intellisense** cannot get the member from the `A`(a second-level struct) so far.

```
template <typename T>
struct C : public B<T>, public A<T> {
    C(T x, T y, T z) : B<T>{ x, y }, z{ z } { }
    T z;

    // when I typed `this->`, Intellisense didn't give me the option `x`,
    // which is iherited from `A<T>` and should appear in the autocomplete pop-up.
    // In contrast, `this->` did give the option `y`.
    void test() { cout <<this->x << ", " << this->y << ", " << z << endl; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I think adding A as another base just to satisfy Intellisense may not be a good idea and may cause potential problems if it's not a simple demo case but a more realistic scenario. Hope this can be fixed soon.