# C++ Clang template “use of undeclared identifier” Compiler Flag

Tags: c++, templates, clang

In Clang compiling this gives me error

```
template<typename TYPE> struct Base
{
   bool variable;
};
template<typename TYPE> struct Ext : Base<TYPE>
{
   void clear() {variable=false;} // <- error here
};
```

> error: use of undeclared identifier.

From [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074), I know a workaround is to use "this->variable", but that's painful to use always, is there any compiler flag to disable this?

I'm looking for a Clang Compiler Flag option to disable this error completely. On MSVC you can do that with "/permissive" command line flag. I was looking for similar option on Clang, and the "-fpermissive" flag doesn't work.

Comment: **Re-posting isn't going to help**

Comment: C++ does not allow this. You need a compiler for a different language.

Comment: Actually it does allow this. But you need `this->variable=false;` to change the lookup rules of `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

(Correction: apparently, some compilers allow disabling this error, see OP above).

In this context `variable` is a dependent name because it is part of `Base<T>` which depends on the template parameter. This is a language requirement.

You can place `using Base<Type>::variable` in your derived class, i.e.

```
template<typename TYPE> struct Ext : Base<TYPE>
{
  using Base<TYPE>::variable;  // <- do this once per class

  void clear() {
    variable = false;          // <- this is fine now
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes you can, on MSVC compiler you have an option "/permissive" that solves this problem. Clang gives you -fms-extensions, and -fpermissive but that didn't help

Comment: Thanks for the correction, bad phrasing from my part. I meant it as in you can only disable "warnings considered as errors/not considered as errors". That being said, the solution above is the best I could think of.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of that, however what I'm going for, is not having to do this at all, because imagine you have 100 variables or methods, writing "using" or extra "this->" that's a huge waste of time IMO. I think compilers should make life easy for programmers, not extra hard.

Comment: @Esenthel : That's fair. One option would be to have one class with all non-templated, shared variables and a separate templated class. Then, you can inherit from both. I tend to avoid multiple inheritance if possible, but it would be an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

It will also work if you use `this->variable` instead of `variable` in the subclass because that changes the lookup rules of variable.

Comment: The question says that OP knows about this, but wants a different solution.