# What makes templates special when there is inheritance involved in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards

What difference in accessibility of variables is there between a normal inheritance and inheritance with templates?

For example the following code will not compile (1)(2):

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T value;
};

template<typename U>
struct B : public A<U> {
    U ret() {
        return value; // Does not compile
    }
};

template<typename U>
struct C : public A<U> {
    U ret() {
        return this->value; // Compiles
    }
};
```

But the following one do compile (3):

```
struct A {
    int value;
};

struct B : public A {
    int ret() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

What part of the standard does create that (rather impractical) difference?

(1): [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/obe4Pqbfh)

(2): The code can actually compile on MSVC except when MSVC is set to compile in C++20 mode

(3): [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9eEvf5q5T)

Comment: Good question! I'm adding [tag:language-lawyer] because I get the feeling we're going to be breaking out the ol' C++ Specification on this one.

Comment: The issue is not the access control, it's name lookup - specifically, two-phase name lookup. Make it `return this->value;` or `return A<U>::value;`, to make `value` a dependent name.

Comment: add `this->` and it works

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Much appreciated, I didn't think about that tag

Comment: The problem is that `A<U>` doesn't necessarily have a member named `value`, since the template can be specialized for any type: `template <> A<int> {}`. So the name lookup rules don't apply unless you say "I really mean it".