# Inheritance in derived class that is a partial specialization of class template

Tags: c++, templates

In the example below, the using declarations from the base class are only inherited by the derived class that is a full specialization of the base class. I was surprised by that at first. Is this because ["members of partial specializations are not related to the members of the primary template"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)? Is that necessary or strongly motivated by some use-case I haven't considered?

Additionally, that would make me expect that the member functions should also be unrelated. If that's the case, why doesn't use of the `override` keyword cause issues?

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Base {
 public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  using TPtr = const T*;
  using UPtr = const U*;

  virtual void TFunc(TPtr t);
  virtual void UFunc(UPtr u);
};

template <typename T>
class PartiallySpecialized : Base<T, int> {
 public:
  // These aren't inherited. 
  using BaseT = Base<T, int>;
  using typename BaseT::TPtr;
  using typename BaseT::UPtr;

  // These are inherited?
  virtual void TFunc(TPtr t) override {}
  virtual void UFunc(UPtr u) override {}
};

class FullySpecialized : Base<double, int> {
 public:
  virtual void TFunc(TPtr t) override {}
  virtual void UFunc(UPtr u) override {}
};

int main() {
  PartiallySpecialized<double> p;
  FullySpecialized f;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not contain any specialization of any template.

Comment: It has to do with dependent name resolution. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer) for an explanation of why.

Comment: our question is very difficult for me to follow. You use wrong terminology. I don't understand what you expected to happen. "// These aren't inherited. " Inherited by who? There is no class clas derives that. " // These are inherited?" Again by who? There is no class that derives that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology, but a declaration of struct `Base<T, int>` would be a partial specialization, would it not?

Comment: @bolov, `PartiallySpecialized` derives from `Base<T, int>`. I expected that a using declaration from the base class would be "inherited" by the derived class. It seem I was wrong (hence the need for new using declarations).

Comment: a template specialization add a specialized definition that differs from the base template. You are not not doing that. The difference between the two is that one is  a template and the base class is dependent on the template parameter and the other is a class with the base class non-dependent. The full answer is in the dupe.

Comment: I see. `PartiallySpecialized` undergoes the two-phase compilation, so both `TPtr` and `UPtr` must be made dependent types in order to pass the first phase of compilation (which comes before checks on instantiations). 

On the otherhand, `FullySpecialized` doesn't undergo two-phase compilation, and when instantiated, the using declarations unambiguously refer to the declarations from the base class.