# c++20 msvc error c3861 base member not found

Tags: c++20, visual-studio-2022

i have a strange problem since i switched the C++ language standard in VS2022 for my c++ project from 17 to 20.

I get compiler error C3861 identifier not found. The indentifier in this case is a member of the base class.

base class:

```
template <class C> class base_vector
{
public:
    base_vector()
    {
    }
    virtual ~base_vector()
    {
    }
protected:
    std::vector<C>  m_vec;
};
```

derived class:

```
template <class C> class child_vector : public base_vector<C>
{
public:
    child_vector()
    {
    }
    virtual ~child_vector()
    {
        m_vec.clear(); // c3861
    }
};
```

When i switch the standard to c++17, no compiler error.

m_vec should be known in child_vector but it's not.
Can anyone see the problem ?
Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m_vec` is a member of a base class dependent on the template parameters.

Until instantiation of the template, the compiler cannot know that `m_vec` is indeed a member of the base class, but it must do name lookup for `m_vec` when parsing the template definition, because `m_vec` isn't a dependent name.

You need to use `this->m_vec` explicitly. `this` is dependent and this form will delay the name lookup until the template parameters and the base class are known.

That has also been the case before C++20. By default MSVC does however do name lookup in a non-standard-compliant way, which is why it works by default. To get the standard-compliant behavior you need to give MSVC the `/permissive-` flag. With the `/std:c++20` flag or later, that flag is implied. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thank you for help. Meanwhile figured out that also __super::m_vec is doing the job.  Your detailed answer is very helpful

Comment: @nullptr Well, that is completely non-standard. If you really want the old MSVC behavior back, you can add the `/permissive` flag (without `-` at the end). See the article I linked. But then your code is not standard C++ and will work only on MSVC.

Comment: No thanks. This pushes me more into direction of standard coding and i appreciate your help.