# In c++ Why and how classname::member syntax can be used for an instance member?

Tags: c++, clion, name-lookup, qualified-name

```
class Human {

public:

    Human(string name);
    string getName() {
        return Human::name;
    }

    void setName(string name) {
        Human::name = name ;
    }
   

private:

    string name;
};
```

Human::name in getName and setName funcs. work perfectly although name is not a static variable.

Why is this happening ?

As far as I know "::" is used to acces functions or static members of a class.

I thought correct usage in getName would be return this -> name or return name.

And even, when generated auto setter function in Clion, setter function uses Human::name not this -> name

I'm coming from java background and in java classname.X  (which resembles classname::X in c++) was only used for static members or functions of a class. That is why I am confused

Comment: Plain `name` would work as well, at least for `getName()` which could just do `return name;`. Won't work in `setName` as you have another variable named `name` is a closer scope, so you need some other way to get the member variable. For example `this->name` or `Human::name`.

Comment: Also, `::` is a *scope* operator. It's not special for `static` class members, it just denotes scope. `Human::name` means "the variable `name` in the scope `Human`".

Comment: Just use "name". The rules (for all of C++) are more complicated than you think. May I recommend [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or two?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: You're missing a return statement in `setName` so you will have **undefined behavior**.

Comment: "Inside classes" you can also refer to static members directly with the name. There is no difference to non-static members. Outside classes the Human::public_nonstatic_variable won't work obviously (static does), not because of the scope notation, but because the instance is obviously not known.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian that cleared things. But still have the question, what are the differences between classname::X and this -> X.  Latter uses pointer but what functionality does it add ?

Comment: For variables, there is no difference, which I know off. For virtual member functions, there is a difference: If you use `baseclassname::x()` in a (e.g. non-overriden) function of the base class to call a virtual (and overridden) member function `x()`, then the base class version is used, if you use `x()` or `this->x()`, the virtually overridden class is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you're missing a return statement inside `setName`, so the program will have **undefined behavior**.

---

Now, `Human::name` is a **qualified name** that refers to(or names) the non-static data member `name`. For qualified names like `Human::name`, **qualified lookup** happens which will find the data member `name`.

On the other hand, just `name`(without any qualification) is an **unqualified name** and so for it, **unqualified lookup** will happen which will also find the data member named `name`. And so you could have just used `name`(instead of `Human::name`) as it will also refer to the same non-static data member.

---

Basically the main **difference** between `name` and `Human::name` are that:

1. `name` is a unqualified name while `Human::name` is a qualified name.
2. For `name` unqualified lookup will happen while for `Human::name` qualified lookup will happen.

---

The **similarity** between the two is that:

1. Both at the end of the day refer to the same non-static data member.

Comment: Thank you. But still have the question, what are the differences between classname::X and this -> X. Latter uses pointer but what functionality does it add ?

Comment: @justauser Both of `classname::X` and `this->X` are qualified names and for both of them qualified lookup will happen and again `this->x` also refers to a member named `x` of the class.

Comment: So, in terms of accessing member named x there won't be any important differences that the programmer should know right ?  I'm quite new to c++ and pointers. Which one do you prefer? And  I wonder why did c++ designers put these 2 diff. ways basically do the same thing ?  (I'm not saying that every problem has a one way solution in syntax , just curious)

Comment: Sometimes(like when we're dealing with templates) we can only use `this->` but not `classname::`. For example, see [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643295/12002570). Basically when dependent names are involved the matter becomes fairly complicated and we must either use `classname::membername` or `this->membername` and just using `membername` will not work. Moreover, in some cases only one of `classname::membername` or `this->membername` works. So they are useful for in different situations.

Comment: @justauser Most C++ programmers prefer to just use the name `x` directly. Some few C++ programmers always use `this->x` to signify that it is a member variable (compared to a local variable or a function parameter). I signify this by prefixing the member variable name with an underscore, i.e. `_x` and leaving out the `this->`. (The variable starts with a lower case and it is a dependent scope, so this is allowed). Some programmers prefix member variable names with `m_`, ,i.e. `m_x`. The `class::` notation is mostly used for inheritance hierarchies, if you want to select a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (6.4.3 Qualified name lookup)

> 1 **The name of a class or namespace member** or enumerator can be
> referred to after the :: scope resolution operator (8.1) applied to a
> nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or
> enumeration. If a :: scope resolution operator in a
> nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup
> of the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, and
> templates whose specializations are types. If the name found does not
> designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the
> program is ill-formed.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful!  But still have the question, what are the differences between classname::X and this -> X. Latter uses pointer but what functionality does it add ?