# What's wrong accessing this nested class from Parent template?

Tags: c++, templates

Here's my code:

```
template <class M, class P>
struct SliderMenuItem : rack::ui::MenuItem {
    struct Slider : rack::ui::Slider {
        Slider(M *module) {
            quantity = new P(module);
            box.size.x = 200.0f;
        }
        virtual ~Slider() {
            delete quantity;
        }
    };

    M *pModule;

    SliderMenuItem(M *module, const char *textMenu) : pModule(module) {
        this->text = textMenu;
        this->rightText = RIGHT_ARROW;
    }
};
template <class M, class P>
struct DelaySliderMenuItem : SliderMenuItem<M, P> {
    DelaySliderMenuItem(M *module, const char *textMenu) : SliderMenuItem<M, P>(module, textMenu) {
    }

    Menu *createChildMenu() override {
        Menu *menu = new Menu;
        menu->addChild(new SliderMenuItem<M, P>::Slider(pModule));
        return menu;
    }
};
```

but it doesn't compile, it says: `error: expected type-specifier menu->addChild(new SliderMenuItem<M, P>::Slider(pModule));`

What's wrong with this nested class from Parent template access?

Comment: `menu->addChild(new SliderMenuItem<M, P>::Slider(pModule));` -> `menu->addChild(new typename SliderMenuItem<M, P>::Slider(pModule));`

Comment: @NathanOliver still doesn't work. It now says "'pModule' was not declared in this scope"... it seems it doesn't inherit the class correctly?

Comment: `this->pModule`

Comment: Woops, forgot you are also trying to access a member from a base class template.  To do that you need to use `this` like `menu->addChild(new typename SliderMenuItem<M, P>::Slider(this->pModule));`  That defers lookup until the template is instantiated.

Comment: [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer). It's the same issue for both, but the question only refers to accessing data members, not member types.