# Is there a magic keyword that can allow me to ‘implicitly’ access all base class members?

Tags: c++, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm using a derived class from a base class using templates. I have something like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class BaseClass
{
    public:
        BaseClass(T e, T f, T g, T h)
        {
            a = e, b = f, c = g, d = h;
        }

    protected:
        T a, b, c, d;
};

template <typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<T>
{
    public:
        //My question is about THIS specific line
        //using BaseClass<T>::a, BaseClass<T>::b, BaseClass<T>::c, BaseClass<T>::d;
        
        //Access and modify base class members once the constructor was called
        DerivedClass(T e, T f, T g, T h) : DerivedClass::BaseClass(e, f, g, h)
        {
            a += e, b += f, c += g, d += h;
        }

        //Access base class members and print them
        void Method2()
        {
            cout << a << endl;
            cout << b << endl;
            cout << c << endl;
            cout << d << endl;
        }

    protected:
      //derived class members
};

int main()
{
    DerivedClass<int> dc(1, 2, 3, 4);
    dc.Method2();
}
```

I'd like to access the base class members in the derived class. The code works well if I include the commented line (output `2 4 6 8`). Otherwise, the compiler can't guess what the members are that I refer to in the derived class.

As far as I could retrieve data from the web, there are two basic ways for telling the compiler to include a base class member in a derived class:

- one uses `this->` before the base member. But I'm too lazy for writing `this->` every time I need to.
- The other one consists of writing `using` for every member I want to access, which I implemented. But I'm also too lazy for writing that magic word for every base class member.

Is there a way to tell the compiler: "Dude, just point to the base class members every time I write their respective names" with one single magic keyword?

To understand better, I replaced the commented line with `using BaseClass<T>` but then I get an error:

> error: expected nested-name-specifier

So, how can I do it?

Comment: [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)

Comment: I see you're also "too lazy" to qualify standard library with `std::`, and instead opted for `using namespace std;` which is almost universally condemned as poor style. Personally, I think `this->a` is ugly, and I'd be inclined to do `using base = BaseClass<T>;` in the class and then access as `base::a` (https://godbolt.org/z/vvY5jrnPj) As a side-note on style, using the comma operator to separate your expressions is not a good idea. Just use semi-colons. The more you resist coding conventions, the harder you become to work with and the more you will struggle to adapt to professional settings.

Comment: Instead of using inheritance, use aggregation i.e. instead of having `BaseClass<T>` as a base of `DerivedClass<T>` make it a member.   Then you can use normal member access  (e.g. if the member is named `m`, use `m.a`, `m.b`, etc).   But I suppose you're "too lazy" for that as well.   [The only other constraint is that `BaseClass` cannot be abstract, but abstract classes with data members are often considered poor technique anyway].

Comment: @Peter thats a good idea, ty. LOL, now everyone will bully me for being lazy. What can I do? Vices are part of the human nature, you can't do anything to eradicate them (cf. Abelard). On the other hand, why is a poor technique having an abstract class with data members?