# Returning structure initialized from template methods in dependent base class

Tags: c++, templates, curly-braces

I have a method in a class template that combines some templated method calls from a dependent base class, which is also a template:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Struct
{
    char c;
    int i;
    double d;
};

template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(T z): x{z} {}

    template <typename U>
    U get() { return static_cast<U>(x); }
private:
    T x;
};

template <typename T>
class Test : public Base<T>
{
public:
    using Test::Base::Base;

    Struct getS()
    {
        return Struct {
            this->get<char>(),
            this->get<int>(),
            this->get<double>(),
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    Struct s{Test<int>(97).getS()};
    std::cout << s.c << ' ' << s.i << ' ' << s.d << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to get an output like `a 97 97`. Instead, when I compile with `g++ std=c++17`, I get the following errors:

```
snip.cpp: In member function ‘Struct Test<T>::getS()’:
snip.cpp:30:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
   30 |         return Struct {
      |                       ^
snip.cpp:30:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
   30 |         return Struct {
      |                      ^~
      |                      ;
snip.cpp:31:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
   31 |             this->get<char>(),
      |                       ^~~~
snip.cpp:31:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘char’
   31 |             this->get<char>(),
      |                       ^~~~
      |                       ;
```

I have tried removing the `Struct` between `return` and the curly brace to get

```
snip.cpp: In member function ‘Struct Test<T>::getS()’:
snip.cpp:31:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
   31 |             this->get<char>(),
      |                       ^~~~
snip.cpp:31:23: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘char’
snip.cpp:30:16: note: to match this ‘{’
   30 |         return {
      |                ^
snip.cpp:31:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘char’
   31 |             this->get<char>(),
      |                       ^~~~
      |                       ;
snip.cpp:31:27: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
   31 |             this->get<char>(),
      |                           ^
snip.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Struct Test<T>::getS() [with T = int]’:
snip.cpp:40:33:   required from here
snip.cpp:31:23: error: could not convert ‘{<expression error>}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Struct’
   31 |             this->get<char>(),
      |                       ^~~~
      |                       |
      |                       <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

When `get` is not a template on `U` (moving the static casts to `getS`), this works fine. Is it possible to return an instance of `Struct` from `Test::getS` using a brace initializer, and if so, how?

FWIW, I suspect that this is related to how template parsing is done, based on this canonical answer, but I'm not sure how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643295/2988730.

Comment: `Struct` after return is unnecessary in C++17.

Comment: `this->template get<char>()` et al - https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/817643

Comment: @273K. Good point. The error changes slightly in that case. Updated

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. Thank you as always. I wish my C++ search-fu was better :)

Comment: Apparently I can't close my own question as a duplicate unilaterally. Please feel free to do it for me.

Comment: I wish it was search fu. I just lurk here too much

Comment: *Apparently I can't close my own question as a duplicate unilaterally* Weird. I could do it with my question.

Comment: @273K. That might be because you have C++ dupe hammer. I can close my own python questions for sure.