# Constants defined in template classes 

Tags: c++, templates, g++, template-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GCC problem : using a member of a base class that depends on a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405/gcc-problem-using-a-member-of-a-base-class-that-depends-on-a-template-argument)

I thought I was familiar with C++, but apparently not familiar enough.
The problem is when you define a constant in a template class, you can use the constant in new classes that derive from that class, but not new *template* classes that derive from it.

For example, gcc says

> test.h:18: error: ‘theconstant’ was not declared in this scope

when I try to compile this (simplified) header file:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T> class base
{
  public:
    static const int theconstant = 42;
};

class derive1 : public base<size_t>
{
  public:
    derive1(int arg = theconstant) {}
};

template<typename T> class derive2 : public base<T>
{
  public:
    derive2(int arg = theconstant) {} // this is line 18
};
```

So the problem is that one class, `derive1`, compiles fine, but the other class, `derive2`, which is a template specialisation, does not.
Now maybe gcc's error is not clear enough, but I don't understand why the constructor in `derive2` would have a different scope than the one in `derive1`.
In case it matters, this happens during compilation of the header file itself, not when instantiating an object of type `derive2<type>`.

I also know what to change to make this compile, so I'm not really looking for one-line pieces of code as answers. I want to understand *why* this happens! I tried searching the web, but apparently I'm not using the correct search arguments.

Comment: FWIW, this same code compiles fine in VC++ 2010. This might be a bug in GCC...

Comment: `derive2(int arg = base<T>::theconstant) {}` compiles fine.

Comment: @dsharlet - not a bug on GCC's part, as described in the spec.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks for pointing me to the other question. But I still don't understand completely. What can go wrong if the compiler simply fetches the original identifier silently? Can you (or anybody) provide an example of where that would go wrong?

Comment: @jrok I know! But what I want to understand is why this is deemed necessary in derived2 and not in derived1, even if the inheritance is not ambiguous.

Comment: It goes very wrong if there are specializations of the base template without `theconstant` and also global objects with the same name. The standard says that we cannot assume that `theconstant` depends on `T` unless you say so. `base<T>::theconstant` or `this->theconstant` are ways of doing that.

Comment: @dsharlet: Actually a deviation from the standard in VS (does not perform two phase lookup properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this will help you understand:

Your code which does not compile:

```
template<typename T> class derive2 : public base<T>
{
  public:
    derive2(int arg = theconstant) {} // this is line 18
};
```

And the reason why:

```
template <> class base<size_t>
{
  public:
    static const int ha_idonthave_theconstant = 42;
};
derive2<size_t> impossible_isnt_it;
```

The specialization!!! Compiler at your line 18 cannot be sure that you will not specialize the base<> in the way that this constant will not be present there at all.

Comment: That makes so much sense that I wonder why it didn't occur to me... I did try with a specialised template, only containing the same member with a different value, and I couldn't make it not work. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
template<typename T> class derive2 : public base<T>
{
  public:
    derive2(int arg = base<T>::theconstant) {} // this is line 18
};
```

Basically you've specified the incomplete scope for the "theconstant".

Comment: Yeah, that was mentioned in the comments. But what I want to understand is why this is deemed necessary in `derived2` and not in `derived1`, even if the inheritance is not ambiguous. In what way is the scope incomplete?

Comment: I guess it has to do something with the "lazy" template instantiation. There is _no_ 'base' class known to the compiler at the time it parses 'theconstant' in derive2.  Once you use the base<T>, you force compiler to "get familiar" with the base<>

Comment: I'll have to think about this.