# gcc can't find base class object

Tags: c++

The following code doesn't compile with gcc, but it compiles with clang.

```
struct Base {
  void base() {}
};

template< typename T >
struct Foo : Base {

  struct Bar : Base {
  };

  struct Baz : Bar {
    void f() {
      base();
    }
  };
};

int main() {
  Foo<int>::Baz{}.f();
}
```

gcc spits the following error:

```
13:11: error: cannot call member function 'void Base::base()' without object
   13 |       base();
      |       ~~~~^~
```

Interestingly, if I change it to `this->base();` or `Base::base();`, then it compiles.

Why can't gcc find the `Base` class object? `Baz` is clearly a subclass of `Base`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, it's the same issue as in this question:

[GCC issue: using a member of a base class that depends on a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405/gcc-issue-using-a-member-of-a-base-class-that-depends-on-a-template-argument?rq=1)

Inside of a template, the compiler does not examine a base class template, and therefore does not find the `base()` method, without adding `this->` or `Base::`.

Comment: "Inside of a template, the compiler does not examine the base class": This is not quite right. The base class must be a template, too, in order to run into the problem. Try to derive `Baz` from `Base` directly and it works. The key in the example is that the intermediate class `Bar` depends on a template parameter, and `Baz` derives from that templated class. I guess it plays no role that both are defined as nested classes. So yes, I think you need to use `this->base()` as explained in the linked post, and that gcc (and also MSVC) are right to reject the code while clang has a bug.

Comment: @Sedenion: Thanks, you are right! I was thinking of 'Bar' from the example when I wrote this (where it being a template is not directly visible), but yes, in general it does need to be a template! I've corrected my answer!